# A notation for a variable which is insignificant in computation?

Tags: notation

I want to explicitly show that when applying a formula certain variables on LHS of the equation are very small and will not be used in computing the RHS. I was curious if there is an actual notation for that.

E.g., $A + \frac{C}{D} \approx B$ where $A$ is so small it's insignificant in the context. Is there something I can replace $A$ with to show explicitly that this variable is the one which get's omitted.

Comment: This is very similar to the idea of 'big O notation'. In this case, I would write something like $ B = \frac{C}{D} + \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: Little-o notation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation : perhaps something like $\frac{C}{D} + \omicron(\frac{C}{D})$ ?

Comment: My first choice was little-o, but that's already been said. My second choice is:
$$A<<{C\over D}$$